# Python 3 cow and pig game from practicepython.org

Tags: python

The game is to generate 4  random numbers. The user is to guess a number. If the wrong guess then the user gets a pig. If the guess is correct user gets a cow.
I know there are solutions there. I am trying to understand whats wrong with my code. 
 the board won't print and I keep getting an error at the semicolon line 15.

```
 import random 
    s = []
    s[0] = randint(0,9)
    s[1]=  randint(0,9)
    s[2] = randint(0,9)
    s[3]=  randint(0,9)
    board = ('s[0] + ' | '+ s[1] +' | '+ s[2] +' | '+ s[3]')
    # user guess a number
    u1 = input('Your Name')
    pig= 0
    cow = 0
    match = 0
    while match != 4:
        uu = int(input("Enter a number 0-9")#user input
        if uu == s[0]:
             s[0].replace(uu)
             cow +=1
        elif uu == s[1]:
             s[1].replace(uu) 
             cow+=1
        elif uu == s[2]:
               s[2].replace(uu)
             cow +=1
        elif uu == s[3]:
             s[3].replace(uu)
             cow += 1
        else:
             print('Wrong')
             pig = 0
        continue
print (u1+ ' Your cows ' + cow " and pigs "+ pig)
```

Comment: Double check your quotes on the `board = ...` line. Could you include the entire error message you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- index assignment to list requires the list to hold a value at that index.
- you cannot print `int + str`
- you cannot compare `int` with `str` --> here I chose to cast the random code into `str`
- Some typos included a misplaced quote, some other typos that I do not remember, and an Oxford comma.
- I have not checked the logic of your game, but you are now able to run and test it. (note that 10 colors are a lot for mastermind, the original had 5, or maybe 6, tops)

Here is your code with the above corrections:

```
import random

s = [0]*4
s[0] = str(random.randint(0, 9))
s[1] = str(random.randint(0, 9))
s[2] = str(random.randint(0, 9))
s[3] = str(random.randint(0, 9))

board = (s[0] + ' | ' + s[1] + ' | ' + s[2] + ' | ' + s[3])

# user guess a number
u1 = input('Your Name')

pig = 0
cow = 0
match = 0

while match != 4:
    uu = int(input("Enter a number 0-9"))  #user input
    if uu == s[0]:
         s[0].replace(uu)
         cow += 1
    elif uu == s[1]:
         s[1].replace(uu)
         cow += 1
    elif uu == s[2]:
         s[2].replace(uu)
         cow += 1
    elif uu == s[3]:
         s[3].replace(uu)
         cow += 1
    else:
         print('Wrong')
         pig = 0
    continue

print(str(u1) + ' Your cows ' + str(cow) + ", and pigs " + str(pig))
```